# Date format: YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: formatting, datetime

Currently I put the date in my document using: `\date{\today}`

How do I display the date in the [`YYYY-MM-DD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601) format?

Comment: See here http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime From the documentation (pg 10) we have *The option `yyyymmdd` makes `\today` produce `YYYY/MM/DD` date*

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**edit:** As noted by @Sean Allred, `datetime` has been superseded by [datetime2](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2), which defaults to `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Using the package [datetime](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime) with the option `yyyymmdd` as

```
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}
```

you just change the value of `\dateseparator` to replace the default `/` by `-` (or `--` if you want).

```
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{--}
```

Also as noted by @Vincent, you can define your own date format.

[image]

Comment: Somebody should check whether ISO 8601 says that the separator has to be - or --. (http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm). Definitely YYYY/MM/DD should not be used - that would violate the standard. Keith

Comment: @KeithB, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles) claims, “The separator used between date values (year, month, week, and day) is the hyphen”. Also, it’s unlikely the standard mandates characters encoded neither in EBCDIC nor ASCII.

Comment: note: `datetime` has been superseded by `datetime2`

Comment: Sigur is correct. However, note that the datetime package must come after the babel package. Babel seems to change the format as well.

Comment: According to the CTAN page, `datetime` is now obsolete and has been replaced by `datetime2`.

Comment: @MichaelMior This is in the 1st line of the answer.

Comment: So it is **facepalm**

Comment: @KeithB for separation: tl;dr: simply - as in „The separator used between date values (year, month, week, and day) is the hyphen, while the colon is used as the separator between time values (hours, minutes, and seconds).“[0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Original documents unfortunately are behind a paywall, some libraries will have free access though.

Answer (score 51):

My solution needs no packages. The only thing you need to know is that the primitive registers `\day`, `\month` and `\year` include the desired information:

```
\def\mydate{\leavevmode\hbox{\the\year-\twodigits\month-\twodigits\day}}
\def\twodigits#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\the#1}

The date in my format: \mydate.
```

Comment: worked just fine in 2019. thanks!

Comment: You can also use the internal `\two@digits` macro, which is defined as `\two@digits=macro: #1->\ifnum #1<10 0\fi \number #1.`

Comment: @user94293 No, I can't use such macro, because it is defined in the `latex.ltx` file. But I don't load such file.

Comment: I like this, but what if we want to write the full name of the month instead of the `\twodigits` format?

Comment: @KennethOdle TeX provides `\ifcase` command. You can use `\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or ...\or November\or December\fi`.

Answer (score 37):

Use the package [datetime2](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2)

```
\usepackage[style=iso]{datetime2}
```

Comment: This should be an edit to the other answers using `datetime` since `datetime` is now superseded and should no longer be used for new documents.

Comment: `datetime2 Error: 'iso' is not a recognised dialect.`

Comment: sorry but I do not see how this package is useful. It seems to force you to manually enter the date values, which it then formats.... so why not just manually write them yourself in the correct format in the document? What is this accomplishing? This answer does not actually show how to use the `datetime2` to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: The package option should be `style=iso`, but a numeric YYYY-MM-DD style is the default anyway, so it's not needed.

Comment: @user5359531 `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{datetime2}\begin{document}\today\end{document}` is a basic MWE that prints the current date as YYYY-MM-DD style. As for specific dates, the syntax is `\DTMdate{2018-06-07}` but the formatting depends on the style. So while it does just display 2018-06-07 for the default style, if you change the style it will display the date in a different format.

Answer (score 26):

According to the link of Sigur:

```
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{specialdate}{\THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY}}
\date{\specialdate\today}
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the package [`isodate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/isodate)

```
\usepackage[iso,german]{isodate}
```

It offers various options (and needs one of its language options) and commands to change the date format.

Comment: This does not answer "How do I display the date in the YYYY-MM-DD format?" and would be more useful with an actual code sample.

Comment: It seems to change how `\today` works if you import it after `datetime`.

Answer (score 6):

Recently (May, 2018), Donald P. Goodman III created the new [package `texdate`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/texdate/texdate.pdf).

From the package documentation:

> It can print dates, advance them by numbers of days, weeks, or months,
>   determine the weekday automatically, and print them in (mostly)
>   arbitrary format. It can also print calendars (monthly and yearly)
>   automatically, and can be easily localized for non-English languages.

For example, the YYYY-MM-DD format of today is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{texdate}
\begin{document}
\initcurrdate
\printfdate{ISOext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to get today's date in YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
\newcommand\twodigits[1]{%
   \ifnum#1<10 0#1\else #1\fi
}

\number\year-\twodigits{\number\month}-\twodigits{\number\day}

Dear Mary,

Today I have received what I need to tell you;
I was taking a walk and I finally know what advice to give.
In the words of the great Kanye West, 
\textit{"If you have the opportunity to play this game called life, 
you have to appreciate every moment."} 
Keep striving toward success, and that is what you will become.


Also linux $>$ windows.

Best, \\
John Doe
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You could probably simplify `\twodigits` by just conditioning for the prefix: `\newcommand{\twodigits}[1]{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi#1}`. Also, your output doesn't include the `-`s.

Comment: @Werner I forgot to create a .jpg that reflected the dashes in the above code; It is only the result pic that doesn't show the dashes. When you execute the code the dashes are present.