# Changing the default date or time in the \titlepage macro

Tags: beamer

The `\titlepage` page macro in `beamer` class  creates a slide with the current date. How to change the date of this macro to some other value and then call `\titlepage`?

Comment: Use `\date{}` and fill it as you wish. Also, see this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152394/14757

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just write `\date{here you write your own date}` 
in your title definition.