# Strange side-effect in beamer: Text in columns in titlelike color after \maketitle

Tags: beamer, titles

There seems to be a strange side-effect in `\maketitle` in `beamer`; see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{madrid}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=orange}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\title{List of Donald Duck universe characters}
\author{Walt Disney}

\begin{document}

\frame{\maketitle}

\begin{frame}{Testslide}
Text before the columns in black
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.62\textwidth}
Some text in \texttt{titlelike} color
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.38\textwidth}
Some more text in black
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Only the text in the first of both columns has the same color as the title.
It also happens without the `\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=orange}` statement, but who sees white text on a white background?
It does *not* happen if `\maketitle` is not invoked. `\titlepage` instead of `\maketitle` has the same effect.

Any work-around for this?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350309/strange-interaction-between-beamer-and-tcolorbox/350437#350437 Does an update help?

Comment: Yes, let me confirm that the update indeed fixes the color bug! How can I mark this question as  "answered"?
I'm having another issue with the date appearing as YYYY-MM-DD instead of DD.MONTH YYYY, but I could not reproduce it in an MWE yet.

Comment: Don't worry about marking it as answered, I marked it as duplicate instead.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152392/date-format-yyyy-mm-dd help for you date problem?

Comment: Not really, since I *want* it to be displayed in the default format. It seems I've found the culprit, see [this question of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352539/date-format-changed-by-loading-pdfcomment-package#352539).