# Date format changed by loading pdfcomment package

Tags: pdfcomment, datetime2

It seems by loading the `pdfcomment` package, the date format is implicitly changed to YYYY-MM-DD.
Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{pdfcomment}
%\pdfcommentsetup{author=me, color=yellow, open=true}

\title{Example in \LaTeX}
\author{rotton}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Example section}

Today is \today.
%\pdfcomment{This changes the date format}

\end{document}
```

Date appears as expected both in the title and text. When you comment in the first, first+second or all three lines related to `pdfcomment` and recompile, the date now appears as YYYY-MM-DD. A short test shows this to be independent of `\documentclass` and language settings.
The [`pdfcomment` manual](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment/doc/pdfcomment.pdf) states that one of the required packages is `datetime2`.

Is this behavior intended, or just an unwanted side-effect?
If the latter, how to get the original date format back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should activate the localization of datetime2:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\DTMsetregional



\title{Example in \LaTeX}
\author{rotton}

\begin{document}


\maketitle

\section{Example section}

Today is \today.
%\pdfcomment{This changes the date format}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, both answers are correct and work. Which one is the "correct answer"? I will opt for this one since it requires less typing.
Anyway, `pdfcomment` should *not* implicitly change the default date format, at least offer an option to disable this behavior.
Would this qualify for a bug report/feature request?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass option `useregional=numeric` to package `datetime2`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{useregional=numeric}{datetime2}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\pdfcommentsetup{author=me, color=yellow, open=true}

\title{Example in \LaTeX}
\author{rotton}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Example section}

Today is \today.

\end{document}
```

[image: useregional=numeric]

See the `datetime2` manual for more values of option `useregional`, e.g.,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{useregional}{datetime2}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\pdfcommentsetup{author=me, color=yellow, open=true}

\title{Example in \LaTeX}
\author{rotton}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Example section}

Today is \today.

\end{document}
```

for

[image: alphanum]

Comment: I just figured in order to keep default format "February 7, 2017" I need to use `\PassOptionsToPackage{useregional}{datetime2}` without the `=numeric` option.