# How do I get \today to display today's date as 14-Sep-2018?

Tags: datetime

What I'm getting now from \today is:

> 14th September 2018

How do I change it to:

> 14-Sep-2018

Comment: See page 96 of this [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf).

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152392/152550) helps.

Answer (score 8):

I think that the easiest way is to redefine `\today` to print this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\today{\number\day-%
  \ifcase\month \or Jan%
  \or Feb%
  \or Mar%
  \or Apr%
  \or May%
  \or Jun%
  \or Jul%
  \or Aug%
  \or Sep%
  \or Oct%
  \or Nov%
  \or Dec\fi-\number\year}%

\begin{document}

  \today

\end{document}
```

For completeness, here is the output:

[image]

Comment: +1 but what's wrong with `\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}` ?

Comment: +1 because you didn't use an external package. :)

Comment: @marmot I guess it’s all a question of what you know:)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it with [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) and [`datetime2-english`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{daymonthsep={-},monthyearsep={-},ord=omit,abbr}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: 15-Sep-2018]

You can replace `en-GB` with any of the other English localisation styles that uses a day month year format. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-MT]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-MT]{daymonthsep={-},monthyearsep={-},ord=omit,abbr}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```